# Xamarin Client app communication with native android service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, client-server, aidl

I am currently developing a Xamarin client application that communicates with a native Android Service via AIDL.

If my client requests an array of objects (of a custom class implementing Parcelable interface) from the Android service, the communication works fine.
But if my client requests a single object (of the same custom class) from the Android service, the app crashes with "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Bad magic number for Bundle exception”.

I have attached parts of my code for reference.

( **Note : Also both type of calls work fine when tested with a native android client.** )

Client - Server interface declaration

```
interface ITestService {

ABC getABCObject();
ABC[] getABCObjectArray();
}
```

ABC.java -(Server side)

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ABC> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ABC>() {
@Override
public ABC createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
Log.i(TAG, "Inside createFromParcel");
return new ABC(source);
}

@Override
public ABC[] newArray(int size) {
Log.i(TAG, "Inside newArray");
return new ABC[size];
}
};
```

ABC.cs - (Xamarin client)

```
public static readonly GenericParcelableCreator<ABC> Creator = new GenericParcelableCreator<ABC>((parcel) => new ABC(parcel));

[ExportField("CREATOR")]
public static GenericParcelableCreator<ABC> GetCreator()
{
    Log.Debug (Tag, "GenericParcelableCreator ");
    return Creator;
}

public sealed class GenericParcelableCreator<T> : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
    where T : Java.Lang.Object, new()
{
    public readonly Func<Parcel, T> _createFunc;
    public GenericParcelableCreator(Func<Parcel, T> createFromParcelFunc)
    {
        Log.Debug (Tag, "GenericParcelableCreator" );
        _createFunc = createFromParcelFunc;
    }

    #region IParcelableCreator Implementation

    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        Log.Debug (Tag, "CreateFromParcel" );
        return _createFunc(source);
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {

        Log.Debug (Tag, "NewArray" );
        return new T[size];
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi I am also facing same problem, did you get any solutions for this?

Comment: No we had to change the interface to return an array of objects